# Copy&Paste Clipboard RTF C#

Tags: c#, richtextbox

i try to copy a table with Pictures from a WPF Richtextbox to a Forms Richtextbox above clipboard.
Both are only code-generated. Not a big Thing, but it will not work.

```
  tmp_rtf_wpf.SelectAll();
                       
  tmp_rtf_wpf.Copy();
//But if i add a Messagebox here, it works
  tmp_rtf_forms.Paste();
//or if i add a Messagebox here, it works too
```

So i think, the Copy()  is not finished. (if Messagebox is shown the Picture with Table is in the Clipboard, and without Messagebox - if i later read the Clipboard the Picture it is inside too, if i use only text and no Picture, it is the same)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, finally i use this as a "workaround":

```
TextRange tr = new TextRange(tmp_rtf_wpf.Document.ContentStart,
                                tmp_rtf_wpf.Document.ContentEnd);
                        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
                        tr.Save(ms, DataFormats.Rtf);
                        string wpfrtf_tmp = ASCIIEncoding.Default.GetString(ms.ToArray());

                        Clipboard.SetText(wpfrtf_tmp, TextDataFormat.Rtf);
 tmp_rtf_forms.Paste();
```